# Redacting and combining ID cards (college ID, passport, license, 4 H club)

Tags: mobile, registration, mobile-web, privacy, material-design

I need a UI that will encourage privacy, and allow a user to selectively disclose information on a need-to-know basis, in real life and online.  This can be ANY information, from a catalog of sorts including:

- Person - Age (date, or older or younger than X), state of residence
- College - StudentID, GPA, club membership & standing, alumni, graduation year
- etc....

**Use cases**

- A woman goes to a bar and shows her license.  That contains her home address.  The bartender or bouncer now knows where she lives, when all they needed was a photo and that she was > 21.
- A person needs to use their medical benefits, but must do so anonymously.  All they need to know is that the person is valid under a current plan, and doesn't need the subscriber ID or to pinpoint that person in any way.
- A minor needs to access an age controlled website, reducing the risk that no online predators can access it.

I imagine implementing this on a mobile device (iOS, Android, etc) or on a website.  Watch form factors (Apple/Android) will come later.

**Question**

What UI should I use to allow users to

- Redact / hide / cross out information they don't want others to see?
- Selectively disclose more sensitive information (home address, driver's ID number)
- Combine information from various sources to create a new ID card (passport, DMV, college ID)

Thanks for helping me figure out the correct UI for this.  My current life passion is to share this amazing technology with as many people as possible, and I need to make sure that it's easy for all ages, on a variety of devices.

**Edit - ideas**

I was thinking of having a top row of frequently (context sensitive) ID cards that can be "favorited".  These cards can be [flippable](http://burkeholland.github.io/kendo-flippable/) 
[image]

....with these swipes on the back:

[image]
[image]

New items (such as a photo from a passport) can be added through a search field or a hierarchal navigation that is done through a set of screens

[image]

To make things more intuitive, I think the bottom of the unflipped card needs to have an EDIT button, and a SEND button...Why? because it's not clear that flipping a card over allows you to redact.   Then again I want this to be a material design...

**Edit - data location**

This data is not stored on your phone; it's password encrypted on a smartcard or downloaded from the internet with a SMS validation.  This concept is more secure than logging into a website (IRS, DMV, College, Equifax, etc) and gaining full access to everything.

Additionally, the data can downloaded to your home computer via a private [Bittorrent](https://www.getsync.com/), or open source [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/).

The data is always encrypted - in air or at rest.  Even if someone steals it.  You can remote-wipe your device if you so choose.

**Edit - How is it validated**

The bartender validates it on his app using transparent cryptography, transmitted over Bluetooth, Wifi, or TLS

Comment: Do you have any ideas? Mockups? Woreframe? How have you started with the same?

Comment: @merqri I added a concept ....

Comment: How will the bartender (for example) be able to trust this information? A driver's license/passport are created by the state under rigorous protocols that try to prevent counterfeiting. How will this app be trustworthy?

Comment: Additionally, why would I want to put ALL of my sensitive information into ONE location? Especially one location (my phone) that can easily be lost or stolen?

Comment: @Voxwoman has great points. Why should people trust this application? What makes it "official" or "trustworthy?"

Comment: @Majo0od - The app will be open source.  The cryptography up for public examination.  There will be audits, 3rd party, and more.  That is how I will gain trust.  Also, I'm just an app provider, anyone can be an app provider.  Anyone can be a "validator".  Trust is always negotiated between the user and bartender.  This app makes the negotiation of trust easier.

Comment: @Voxwoman I updated the question.  All your information is on the net already with a a simple username and password.  I'm giving people a technology to control *where* it is and *who has it*.    How will someone trust the app?   That I will be publishing later, but I have addressed this, and am in discussion with various state and local governments.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @MattObee - I'm looking for a UI that is suitable, and not being a UX designer, this is what I came up with.  Is it sufficient?

Comment: Combining info goes well beyond UI -- it's decidedly nontrivial to implement it from a technical perspective, because you somehow need to classify all things everyone might need on an ID card (e.g.: my university ID has two separate ID numbers, so you can't assume there's one ID number per type of card). Also, is the idea that they can combine fields from different issuers on one card (e.g. passport number and school student status)? If so, how do you plan to handle things like one part of a card expiring while the rest is valid from a UX perspective?

Comment: @cpast A combined card takes the expiration date of the ID that ends soonest

Comment: The value of this app comes from all parties in the transaction having the app. That's going to be difficult to pull off in industries like bartending (where the bartender is unlikely to be using a phone while working) or healthcare (were technical adoption varies by location). Have you considered focusing on a specific industry or single use case as the MVP for the app?

Comment: @mhick Im open sourcing it and allowing anyone to build on it.  I will just overcome the first barrier of adoption / technical challenge for everyone

Answer (score 2):

Considering the context of use and the user story, there must be a quick to deploy, yet routinely and robustly secure display of data.

A scene based approach would conceptually strongest UX. e.g. User selects a scene

> - need to prove I am **legal drinking age** in this State
> - need to prove level of **medical cover**
> - need to prove I am in an **age range**
> - need to prove I am a **member of** organisation X

how this is presented is secondary importance. Presentation must be driven out from the most common scenes and how they relate e.g. hierarchical? does a scene need secondary context input?

Note that

- Provide multiple default scenes
- Default scenes can pick best method of proof from the data available
- Scenes can merge data from different sources e.g. *Hire a car* has proof of drivers license and sufficient funds
- Lock phone when a scene is active (so user can hand to official without risk)
- Allow for custom scenes to be created

An additional low frequency use case may to extend amount of data revealed on current scene, BUT before you implement make sure this is a really required case.

Remember **the official validating a stated claim is a user too**, so any COMPLETE UX design must include their wider use cases too.  Can they get independent proof of the claim made on applicants phone?  e.g. Possibly scan a QR code on their phone and see verification message.

Comment: Love it! I'll be adapting what I have already into a draft form in a few weeks

Comment: @LamonteCristo If you love it, then up-vote it please, as I just did.

Comment: Whoa, I thought I upvoted on the mobile app... +1 again.  Thanks for the heads up @JeromeR

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not stipulate how the user will deliver the desired information. I see 2 methods, physically delivering the card/ID to the recipient, and digitally providing the data. The latter doesn't fit your use cases, so I'll answer for the former.

The answer is challenging because there are multiple ways to accept information inputs, but the information comes in a physical form. Use case #1, for instance, makes no sense because bouncers aren't looking to see if the person is 21. Most new drivers licenses (their biggest use case) actually say when the person turns 21 by year. They care about the legitimacy of the card, which you cannot prove except by handing the card over. A photo and additional info, especially if it's digitized, can be declined as fake and fabricated.

Hurray physicality.

The other use cases fall under the same issues. So I answer with a question: what exactly are you trying to solve.

It sounds like you're looking for a way to collect "user" data that's relevant for the use case in question. If so, that's easy: map out all of the types of data inputs (drivers licenses, IDs, passports, etc.) in physical form, build an app that makes the camera scan that determines which input type it is, and then only display and highlight those data points.

Conceptually, it's easy. Technically...if you can find a team that can build it, give me the routing number for your company.

Assuming you have access to hundreds if not thousands of different government databases to answer the questions above in a simple fashion, awesome. But this is some Minority Report stuff.